# How to implement okta authorization workflow with an ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, okta

I'm trying to set authentication/authorization for an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project using the authentication flow, but I'm facing some issues with the callback and how to handle the authentication response.

So far I managed to get the okta authentication window of my company, proceed with the username/password input, complete the 2-step verification and get a callback url that ends nowhere...

I was expecting the `OnCreatingTicket` to intercept the callback and do "something" but it never goes there. I just get redirected to No webpage was found for the web address:

```
http://localhost:4200/callback?code=XXX&state=XXXX
```

What am I missing?

My `program.cs` looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

#if DEBUG

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

#endif

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Okta";
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
})
.AddOAuth("Okta", options =>
{
    // Oauth authentication middleware is second

    var oktaDomain = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaDomain");
    var oktaAuthority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:OktaAuthority");

    // When a user needs to sign in, they will be redirected to the authorize endpoint
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = $"{oktaDomain}/oauth2/{oktaAuthority}/v1/authorize";

    // Okta's OAuth server is OpenID compliant, so request the standard openid
    // scopes when redirecting to the authorization endpoint
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.UsePkce = true;
    // After the user signs in, an authorization code will be sent to a callback
    // in this app. The OAuth middleware will intercept it
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

    // The OAuth middleware will send the ClientId, ClientSecret, and the
    // authorization code to the token endpoint, and get an access token in return
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientId");
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Okta:ClientSecret");
    options.TokenEndpoint = $"{oktaDomain}/oauth2/{oktaAuthority}/v1/token";

    // Below we call the userinfo endpoint to get information about the user
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = $"{oktaDomain}/oauth2/{oktaAuthority}/v1/userinfo";

    // Describe how to map the user info we receive to user claims
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "given_name");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            // Get user info from the userinfo endpoint and use it to populate user claims
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            context.RunClaimActions(user);
        },

    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

#if DEBUG

app.UseCors();

#endif

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

Comment: Have you check if your token endpoint valid?